# "Battery saver" feature killing my music service

Tags: android, service, streaming

I'm building a music streaming app for Android.

In this app, I have a `Service` which is responsible for playing audio from an HTTP server. Before playing, I make sure to `startForeground()` and acquire a partial `WakeLock`, so that my service isn't killed. I also get a `WifiLock`, just in case.

The service works fine... as long as my phone isn't on "battery saving mode". The minute I turn on battery saving and disconnect my phone from power source, my service is killed with fire!

Unfortunately it doesn't even seem that `onDestroy()` is called, so my notification from `startForeground()` stays visible, even if the service is dead.

The phone is a Samsung Galaxy S6, with Android 6.0.1 on it.

Two questions:

1. Is there a way I can keep the service alive despite the battery saver thingy?
2. If not, I'd like to know at least when my service is killed, so that I can do a bit of cleanup (remove notification & internal stuff).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem? I have similiar case - depending on device and exact Android version either app or wifi connection gets stopped ignoring all the wakelocks

Comment: I don't know of any fix for that. Not sure it has even been fixed in Android 7 actually... My app was not the only one: even google music and spotify had the issue.

Comment: Android 7 still has the issue. Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible by using a foreground service **in a separate process** holding a partial wakelock.

```
android:process="process_name"
```

(documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html)

Note that you shouldn't use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) in a multi-process environment.

See also this issue: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=193802

Comment: This doesn't seem to work unfortunately, unless I'm doing something wrong.  I've put different process for application and service, and still no improvement. Something like `<application android:process=":org.aspyct.myapp"><service android:process=":org.aspyct.myapp.service"/>`. Can you spot something wrong?

Comment: I think it was meant to put a service in a separate process